# New chain snaps after shop service

Tags: chain

I changed my chain on my bike last week for a new 9-speed SRAM chain. When I did this it became apparent that my cassette was worn beyond use, so I took my bike for a service at my local shop. They replaced the cassette, did some repairs to the rear hub & truing of the wheel, replaced all cables & cable housing, and aligned the dérailleurs. The chain was the correct length & fitted properly by me last week... ([Risks/problems of a short chain](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/24316/risks-problems-of-a-short-chain))

I think I should go to the shop and ask for a replacement chain (free of charge). **Given the work the shop did, is it likely that the shop would have removed & reattached the chain and therefore, could they have damaged it?**

Comment: Is the new cassette the same size as the old cassette? Also, when you put the SRAM  chain on, did you use the quick link? You can do all the things mentioned without removing the chain, so I'm guessing its your fault or just bad luck.

Comment: But last week the chain was not the correct length.  Did you add length to the chain?

Comment: @Blam I replaced the whole chain after attempting to reinsert links, the chain seized. It's in the comments of the above link

Comment: @Batman Same size cassette, chain was attached correctly by me, and used the quicklinks. Break in the chain was in a regular link, just two links from the quicklink. So seems probably just bad luck...

Comment: Seize and snap are not the same.  You don't know the shop damaged that chain.

Comment: @blam I mean the chain seized when I reinserted links, so I just bought a new chain and made it the right length from the beginning. The new chain then snapped yesterday evening.

Comment: I'd echo @Batman's comment that none of the jobs you mention necessitate removing the chain. Even if they did remove it, you'd expect the mechanic to find the quicklink and split it there. I think therein lies your problem - what do you say when the shop says "we didn't touch the chain"? You may have to take the hit here.

Comment: @PeteH I think I'll try to push the blame to manufacturer then, feels like the shop is more likely to be nice if I don't accuse them...

Comment: I doubt you're going to get anywhere with this, without expending significantly more than the 10 dollars a chain costs (in effort). I'm going to guess that it broke at a link which you shortened the chain at, though.

Comment: How did you close the chain? You shouldn’t re-use normal pins, they are riveted (you’d need an expensive Rohloff Revolver which is capable of riveting). Only use dedicated connecting pins or master links. If you re-used a normal pin it’s totally your fault.

Answer (score 1):

The work they did doesn't require the chain to be removed (as others have mentioned).  It could be a defect but once again, the prices of chain are way to cheap to worry about it.  Given the volume of chain SRAM puts out, one in a million chance.  The rest of the chain is fine however so remove the broken link and keep on riding.

When adding links, chain pins can be tricky to get right.  It requires a close eye and very small adjustments to make sure the pin is in correctly.  Take note that when using chain tools, it will squish the link parts tightly together so that they do not move.  You have to then apply force in the opposite direction to make them move freely.  I learned all this from a Bicycle Tutor video (now pay-walled last time I checked), but I'm sure Youtube has more.

The first time I had to replace a chain, I made it too short at first, but then added some to it.  It worked great for a week until it popped just as I was leaving for work (well a mile down the road).  It failed at the spot that I had to add the links at.  I pushed the pin in too far and didn't give the plate enough pin to bite into.

I have done a few more chains since then and found that I have to go slow and make fine adjustments (1/8 of a turn).  Compare with the links around it to make sure it looks right, that the gaps are spaced right, and then only apply just as much force needed to make it move freely.

Comment: Note that `10sp & 11sp Links are POWERLOCK, they fit together but then are not designed to come apart again`.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are they misaligned the gears a little. I've snapped a few new chains and the most common circumstance is after I've messed with my gear indexing (I'd say "sorting out" but breaking a chain indicates it didn't work). There IS a chance that it's just a bad chain but it's also possible you did something wrong too.

I'd call the bike shop and tell them and see what they say rather than accusing them. If you bought the chain online, call the online retailer and speak to them too.